# Audio player randomly stops playing in a WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I created an android app using an android webview the displays an HTML, JS audio (radio) player. It plays for the first 20 - 30 minutes and then stops. I thought that it was the HTML, JS but when I opened it on my computer and played the audio for the same amount of time it did not stop. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the webview that I created.  Can someone look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? Is it possible that the webview is refreshing the page or something of the sort?

Thanks,

Corey

```
package com.madcreationapps.talayradioapp;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
//findViewById returns an instance of View ,which is casted to target class

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//This statement is used to enable the execution of JavaScript.

        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
//This statement hides the Vertical scroll bar and does not remove it.

        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
//This statement hides the Horizontal scroll bar and does not remove it.

        webView.loadUrl("http://surf.hotspotmediaradio.com/");
//This statement hides the scroll bar and does not remove it.
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session

Comment: This is not even remotely to close to what I was asking for help with.

Comment: You want an ongoing process, audio related, in Android. I think this is exactly what you want. I don't know the reaon your streaming stopps, but if you want a WebView based, radio app, This is the best thing for you.